# If $X-M$ is a second category space then $M$ is a first category space

Tags: baire-category

Let $X$ be a complete metric space, let $M \subseteq X$ such that $X-M$ is a second category space prove that $M$ is first category space.

**My attempt**. We know that $X$ is complete metric space, so $X$ is a second category space, and also $$X=(X-M) \cup M,$$
I wanted to do it by contradiction but it doesn't get me anywhere, assuming that $M$ is a second category space.

Comment: Unless I am reading this wrongly, this is false, no? Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ and $M = (0,1)$. Then, $M$ is of the second category and $X \setminus M$ is of the second category too (since it is complete).